# AppleScript/OSX - Sorting Issues

Tags: macos, sorting, applescript, finder

Okay so, I have a script to copy alpha channels from one file to another. The problem comes with the names of the one with the alpha channels having _mask in the name throwing off the sort sometimes.

Example, I have several files -

```
124_CHARCOAL.CR2
124_hangers.CR2
124_INDIGO.CR2
124_RED.CR2
124_TAUPE.CR2
124.CR2

124_CHARCOAL_mask.pdf
124_hangers_mask.pdf
124_INDIGO_mask.pdf
124_mask.pdf
124_RED_mask.pdf
124_TAUPE_mask.pdf
```

Just using ***tell application "Finder" to sort myList by name*** places things (rarely) out of order. Is there some way to fix this, or am I better off just adding some code to strip the _mask part from the file name before sorting and then re-add it back?

Comment: Is the point of the sort so that you can match up the files to grab the correct mask for the correct image?

Comment: Yep. I figured that was easier than "Finding" the name.

Comment: If that's the case, I would follow @PHennessey's answer. Work with your images, loop through them and strip off the .CR2 from the name. Use the new name to grab your "_mask" file. With this approach, you won't have to play the sorting game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this would probably involve setting applescripts text item delimiters to ".CR2" then making a master list of text item 1 of each item in the CR2 list then manually adding "_mask.pdf" to the end of those and manually generating a new list that way.

```
set myList to {"124_CHARCOAL.CR2", "124_hangers.CR2", "124_INDIGO.CR2", "124_RED.CR2", "124_TAUPE.CR2", "124.CR2"} -- this is your original sorted list of CR2 files.

set maskList to {} -- prepare an empty list to receive the correctly ordered mask list.

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ".CR2"
repeat with thisItem in myList
    set baseName to text item 1 of thisItem
    set maskName to baseName & "_mask.pdf"
    copy maskName to end of maskList
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "" -- remember to reset this to nothing
get maskList -- this returns the properly-ordered mask list.
```

Of course, this will only work if your naming conventions don't deviate from what you've shown us here.

Answer (score 0):

What does this list look like when it is sorted improperly, and what should it look like instead?

Comment: The example above is the improper sort order.


For 99% of things though, they are sorting in a 1:1 name order.

Comment: I think your naming convention should be modified so that files with no name aren't just called "124.CR2." It should have an additional part to the name like "main" so it would be called "124_main.CR2." That would automatically resolve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the names are supplied by the client and can't be changed or it will mess with their InDesign spreads. =/ That is good to know though for personal use.